# Return the first empty date in a time frame in an Outlook Calendar

Tags: workflow, calendar, outlook

I want to be able to use Microsoft Flows to be able to find the first date in a period of time in Outlook that doesn't have an event on it.

For Example:

I need to set an event.

Flows searches between 1st January and 31st December.

There are events everyday between 1st January and 31st March

Flows should return the 1st available date which in this case is 1st of April.

Is there a function to do that or is there a method I could use?

Answer (score 0):

It is still in beta, but the [Find Meeting Times](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes) API is what you want.